# Is there Option in Xamarin.Forms to use WPF Controls?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am very new to Xamarin.Forms android , IOS applications.

And I have small project in WPF which have some controls like openGL control, Windows, Usercontrols. And I need to convert my wpf project into Android and IOS Application using Xamarin.Forms.

I will create other UI Components like labels, buttons, Textbox in Xamarin.Forms but i need to use the Same WPF usercontrols, windows in Android , IOS Application.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No.  iOS and Android do not have any mechanism to render these controls.